# SQL Date input worked fine but error now Site is on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have an SQL Query where it inputs the date into the database from a calender in ASP.NET however now I have deployed it to Azure I get this error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" This is the code that I am using in C#

```
        string fromFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        string toFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        string date = diarycalender.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, fromFormat, null);
        string date2 = (newDate.ToString(toFormat));
        DateTime date3 = DateTime.Parse(date2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date3);
```

Can anyone explain why I get this error now when it worked fine locally but not anymore??

Comment: So.. is there a reason you aren't doing `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", diarycalendar.SelectedDate)`?

Comment: is your time zone diff?

Comment: The `CultureInfo` on your local machine is different than the one on the Azure box. You need to explicitly set a culture here.

Comment: ah cool how do i find what culture info to set it to?

Comment: Well if you always want english you can use `en-US`, or you could check out `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Specifically I'm talking about the `DateTime.Parse`/`ParseExact` lines. Also, any reason you're stringifying a date just to parse it back into a `DateTime`? You could use `DateTime date3 = new DateTime(date2.Ticks)` instead

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I don't think he even needs to go that far... given that he's calling `.ToShortDateString()`, I would assume that `diaryCalendar.SelectedDate` returns a `DateTime` to begin with.

Comment: @JasonP: Ah good catch. Yeah `newDate`, `date2, and `date3` are unnecessary, at least with this code

Comment: I will give it a try and hopefully get it worked out, thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

By default Azure websites are created with the US locale, as per this blog post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgolpe/archive/2010/12/29/windows-azure-date-time-and-locale.aspx

It looks as though you want to use the UK locale for your date time, which is why things are running OK locally, but not when you upload the site to Azure.

According to this blog http://yossidahan.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/locale-on-windows-azure/ there are several ways around this problem, the easiest of which should be to include in the system.web of web.config the following:

```
 <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```